# How to fit column wise ordinal encoding

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'grade': np.random.choice(list('AAAD'),size=(5)),
                   'dash': np.random.choice(list('PPPS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': np.random.choice(list('QWRR'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': np.random.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': np.random.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})
```

I would like to get a mapping dictionary based on ordinal encoding technique as given [here](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/0.6.x_a/encoders/OrdinalCategoricalEncoder.html)

```
from feature_engine.encoding import OrdinalEncoder
X = tdf.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y = tdf.target
train_t, test_t, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                test_size=0.25,
                                                random_state=0)
cat_list= tdf.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.tolist()
ordinal_encoders = {}
for col in cat_list:
    print(col)
    ordi = OrdinalEncoder(encoding_method='ordered')
    ordinal_encoders[col] = ordi
    ordi.fit(train_t[col], y_train)
    train_t[col] = ordi.transform(train_t[col])
```

However, I get the below error

> TypeError: X is not a pandas dataframe. The dataset should be a pandas
> dataframe.

How can I fit and transform the ordinal encoder on a column by column basis? I am able to get the encoders initialized as shown below but unable to fit and transform them

```
{'grade': OrdinalEncoder(),
 'dash': OrdinalEncoder(),
 'dumeel': OrdinalEncoder()}
```

I would like to do it this way because later, I wish to finally get the mapping dictionary (ordinal value for each of the catgories and store it in a dictionary)

Comment: What's `OrdinalEncoder`?

Comment: It transforms categorical values into ordered numeric values. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.fit_transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scikit` learn has a so-called `ColumnTransformer` for that exact case. There you can specify various transformers and the columns they should be applied too.
In code, that would roughly read like

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('ord', OrdinalEncoder(encoding_method='ordered'), ['grade', 'dash', 'dumeel'])], remainder="passthrough") # remainder passthrough means that all not mentioned columns will not be touched.
transformed = transformer.fit_transform(tdf)
```

Comment: @TheGreat please remove the comment now, as it leads to a dead link

Comment: Which comment to remove? Scikit learn url works fine..what comment are you talking about?